# What is the best way to resolve CouchDB document conflicts across 2 DB instances?

Tags: couchdb

[image]

I have one application running over NodeJS and I am trying to make a distributed app. All write request goes to Node application and it writes to CouchDB A and on success of that It writes to CouchDB B. We read data through ELB(which reads from the 2 DBs).It's working fine.

But I faced a problem recently, my CouchDB B goes down and after CouchDB B up, now there is document _rev mismatch between the 2 instances.

What would be the best approach to resolve the above scenario without any down time?

Comment: Why don't you use CouchDB's built-in clustering support instead of re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Flimzy Thank you so much for your suggestion. I will try to do that also. But my current application is running on production with couchDB 1.6(I hope it's not supporting clustering) and I can't move that quickly also. Could you please provide some better approach to fix my current problem?

Comment: The easiest solution is going to be to upgrade to CouchDB 2.1. The alternative, is to write the same functionality yourself, which will take much longer, and be more prone to error.

Comment: (Also note, you should never use CouchDB 1.6 any more, due to a serious security flaw recently discovered. Please update immediately to 1.7 or 2.1)

Answer (score 1):

If your CouchDB A & CouchDB B are in the same data centre, then @Flimzy's suggestion of using CouchDB 2.0 in a clustered deployment is a good one. You can have `n` CouchDB nodes configured in a cluster with a load balancer sitting above the cluster, delivering HTTP(s) traffic to any node that is "up".

If A & B are geographically separated, you can use [CouchDB Replication](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.1/replication/index.html) to move data from A-->B and B-->A which would keep both instances perfectly in sync. A & B could each be clusters of 3 or more CouchDB 2.0 nodes, or single instances of CouchDB 1.7.

None of these solutions will "fix" the problem you are seeing when two copies of the database are modified in different ways at the same time. This "conflict" state is CouchDB's way of preventing data loss when two writes clash. Your app can resolve the conflict by picking a winning revision or writing a new one. It's not a fault condition, it's helping your application recover from a data loss during concurrent writes in a distributed system.

You can read more about [document conflicts in this blog post series](https://developer.ibm.com/dwblog/2015/cloudant-document-conflicts-one/).

Comment: Thank you so much for the brief answer. I come across got one articel "Usually replication updates this quickly, but it might take a while due to write load, and if the client sends multiple requests in quick succession, there is a fair chance that updating the document yet another time will hit CouchDB B which will reject the write, because the _rev doesn’t match any more.." Please find this link(https://writing.jan.io/2013/12/19/understanding-couchdb-conflicts.html) for more details. Then in such cases how will we manage?

Answer (score 0):

If both of your 1.6.x nodes are syncing buckets using standard replication, turning off one node shouldn’t be an issue. On node up it receives all updates without having conflicts – because there were no way to make them, the node was down.

If you experience conflicts during normal operation, unfortunately there exist no common general way to resolve them automatically. However, in most cases you can find a strategy of marking affected doc subtrees in a way allowing to determine which subversion is most recent (or more important).

To detect docs that have conflicts you may use standard views: a doc received by a view function has the `_conflicts` property if there exist conflicting revisions. Using appropriate view you can detect conflicts and merge docs. Anyway, regardless of how you detect conflicts, you need external code for resolving them.

If your conflicting data is numeric by nature, consider using CRDT structures and standard map/reduce to obtain final value. If your data is text-like you may also try to use CRDT, but to obtain reasonable performance you need to use reducers written in Erlang.

As for 2.x. I do not recommend using 2.x for your case (actually, for any real case except experiments). First, using 2.x will not remove conflicts, so it does not solve your problem. Also taking in account 2.x requires a lot of poorly documented manual operations across nodes and is unable to rebalance, you will get more pain than value.

BTW using any cluster solution have very little sense for two nodes.

As for above mentioned CVE 12635 and CouchDB 1.6.x: you can use this patch https://markmail.org/message/kunbxk7ppzoehih6 to cover the vulnerability.